# .bat start program and force minimized

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a tiny .bat file that opens 3 programs
One of them should be started minimized:

```
START /MIN C:\PROGRA~2\HOBBYI~1\VLCSET~1\VLCSET~1.exe
```

This program, however, ignores the **/MIN** tag and it cannot be minimized manually either (only has the exit symbol and ignores win+m).

How can I force it to either hide or run minimized?
I am using win 10

Comment: The above is one of 3 lines - it is that specific program that needs to be minimized on start-up and not the .bat file

Comment: Unless the program accepts command line parameters and one of those parameters allows the program to start minimized, what you ask is impossible. Also, it wouldn't hurt to tell us what the program actually _is_.

Comment: The program is this vlc remote: [Android VLC Remote] (http://hobbyistsoftware.com/android/vlc-more)

Answer (score 0):

If the program doesn't allow minimization, you can't minimize it. There might be some ugly hacks to work around this, but that's usually the point where you should ask yourself whether you really want to use a program that doesn't seem to fit your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the following:

```
"cmd.exe /c start /min your_file.bat"
```

If you with the cmd window to close itself once the .bat file has completed, use this:

```
"cmd.exe /c start /min your_file.bat ^& exit"
```

Comment: It's not the .bat file - but the program that it starts that should be minimized. I've added '@echo off' to the .bat and that works fine :-)